# Multiple USB streams at the same time

Tags: usb, speed

Some computers have multiple USB controllers, for example one on the motherboard and one on a PCIe card. Does anyone know [by actually doing it] whether data can be read from two different devices at the same time? I need to get data from more than one instrument but each one takes more than half the USB 2 bandwidth. They are USB2 devices with no USB3 equivalent. If they were on different controllers that is technically possible. I could do it with an embedded processor with two USB controllers. The question is can Windows 7 or 10 do it?

There will be two or more instruments. Each will take close to half the bandwidth of USB2 not so much from the data rate as they are just slow and require several short transfers of query/response for every long transfer. The maximum instrument data rate is 320kB/s. It might be possible to read from two instruments at the rate over a single USB controller but some cases require four or more instruments.

Comment: Is the speed/bandwidth the issue with your USB devices that make them fail, they don't just slow down a little & share the bandwidth? Or is the data time sensitive, or something unusual? And if you've got two different USB controllers, does just plugging one device into each different controller work?

Comment: I have read two video capture streams of ca. 30MByte/s each concurrently many times via independent USB 2.0 channels (both on mainboard) many times. Not on Windows though, but on Linux - but I am quite sure this is OS independent

Comment: USB2 is 60MB/s. That doesn't include overhead which I have been told typically limits the rate to 50MB/s. My data doesn't need to be real time but the closer it is to real time the longer data can be taken before the instrument memory overflows